# Delete all the text before a letter or a number

Tags: python, regex

I have to delete all the text before any letter or number using python.

The string I have to deal can be:

`- Presa di coscienza`

`-3D is better than 2D`

`Basi di ottica`

And the result have to be:

`Presa di coscienza`

`3D is Better than 2D`

`Basi di ottica`

Searching on internet I built this regex:

`^.*?([A-Z]|[0-9])`

It work well but it delete the first letter too. How can I do this?

Comment: You might want to remove the `?` that means 'one of any character' before your capture group. Also, you may include lowercase letters in you capture group.

Comment: You could use a positive lookahead with a negated character class `^[^A-Z0-9\r\n]*(?=[A-Z0-9])` https://regex101.com/r/RFeq0G/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Positive lookahead is your answer:

```
^.*?(?=[A-Z]|[0-9])
```

The extra `?=` makes all the difference:

Positive lookahead will pretty much match any `[A-Z]|[0-9]` group found after the main expression (e.g `^.*?`) without actually including it in the result.

Comment: `[A-Z]|[0-9]` is better written `[A-Z0-9]` and it's more convenient to match also lowercase letters `[A-Za-z0-9]`

Comment: @Toto : Definitively true. `[0-z]` is also a more succinct alternative .
I was just mimicking the OP's original solution. + Maybe he only wants to match uppercase letters ?

Comment: Note that `[0-z]` matches in the ASCII table from decimal value 48 till 122 which is more than `[A-Za-z0-9]`

Answer (score 1):

The pattern that you tried deletes the first letter as it first matches 0 or more times any character using a non greedy quantifier, and then captures either an uppercase char A-Z or a digit 0-9.

That capture is part of the match, and will be deleted as well.

Instead you can use a positive lookahead `(?=[A-Z0-9])` asserting what is directly to the right is either an uppercase char A-Z or a digit using a single character class.

Instead of using the non greedy `.*?` you can use a negated character class matching 0+ times any char except a newline or upper case A-Z or a digit and prevent unnecessary backtracking.

```
^[^A-Z0-9\r\n]*(?=[A-Z0-9])
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[^A-Z0-9\r\n]*` Negated character class, match 0+ times any char except what is listed
- `(?=[A-Z0-9])` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is a char A-Z or digit 0-9

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RFeq0G/1)